# Extent of Google spreadsheet cells

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets cells go from A -> Z and then start doubling up eg AA -> ZZ (presumably - I've only been as far as CA). This allows for 676 cells horizontally. Question is- does anyone *really* use more than this?

Comment: Hopefully that's a no...

Comment: Or it may be 702 cells...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the copy & paste option... :-/ Turns out that there's a 2,000,000 cell limit on the whole worksheet. Roughly, this means you might see cells with three letters sometimes, but for the most part the upper limit is ZZ (it all depends on the depth of your spreadsheet I guess (so you may not even get as far as ZZ sometimes) ).